# Problem installing gtk+ 1.2.10 using MacPorts (putty install)

Tags: putty, macports, gtk

I am trying to install putty, and the process includes installing a bunch of MacPorts packages, including GTK+

The GTK build is failing as follows:

```
:info:build /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gtk\" -DGTK_DISABLE_COMPAT_H -DGTK_LIBDIR=\"/opt/local/var/macports/software/glib1/1.2.10_6/lib\" -DGTK_DATA_PREFIX=\"/opt/local/var/macports/software/glib1/1.2.10_6\" -DGTK_SYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/local/var/macports/software/glib1/1.2.10_6/etc\" -DGTK_LOCALEDIR=\"/opt/local/var/macports/software/glib1/1.2.10_6/lib/locale\" -I.. -DGTK_NO_CHECK_CASTS -DUSE_XIM -DX_LOCALE -I/opt/local/include/glib-1.2 -I/opt/local/lib/glib/include -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -Wall -c gtkmenubar.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gtkmenubar.lo
:info:build In file included from gtkintl.h:7,
:info:build                  from gtkmain.c:56:
:info:build /opt/local/include/libintl.h:440: error: syntax error before 'libintl_newlocale'
:info:build /opt/local/include/libintl.h:440: error: syntax error before 'locale_t'
:info:build /opt/local/include/libintl.h:440: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'libintl_newlocale'
:info:build /opt/local/include/libintl.h:440: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
:info:build make[2]: *** [gtkmain.lo] Error 1
```

---

The appropriate section of libintl.h:

```
#if 1

#undef newlocale
#define newlocale libintl_newlocale
extern locale_t newlocale (int, const char *, locale_t);

#endif
```

---

The only thing that I can see is that the GTK site speaks of dependencies that aren't reflected in port.  Then again, we're not talking about the same version...

Any ideas why this is happening?

-BVE

Comment: GTK1.xx ? Use a new Putty. It uses GTK2. (Guess you can get it from macports or something like that.)

Comment: I'm curious why anyone would install Putty on anything other than Windows. Why not just use the built in SSH (OpenSSH) that's already in Mac OS X?

Comment: @Shiki I believe you're mistaken. The official site PuTTY site, http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ , lists 0.60 as the latest, which is what MacPorts has. The README for 0.60 says it requires GTK+1.2 and that GTK+2 is not supported.

Comment: @Spiff: No I'm not. http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=18161 ; http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=28329 >> both == gtk2.0+

Comment: @Shiki, so when you said, "Use a new Putty", you actually meant, "Use some random person's unofficial fork of Putty"?

Comment: So it is no random LAWL. You use putty, and yet you call latest = random , nice one. It is the latest one, that's all. It IS from the same developer, just built on GTK2. I'm using it for a looong time, checked their source, and they both work fine. You can also check it out.. it's open-source ya' know..